# Find corresponding value with maximum in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I have a list (created from a .csv file) with an output like this:

`[('25.09.2016 01:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '225'), 
('25.09.2016 02:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '173'), 
('25.09.2016 03:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '106'), 
('25.09.2016 04:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '74'), 
('25.09.2016 05:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '84'), 
('25.09.2016 06:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '122'), 
('25.09.2016 07:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '110'), 
('25.09.2016 08:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '177'), 
('25.09.2016 09:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '301'), 
('25.09.2016 10:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '552'), 
('25.09.2016 11:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '812'), 
('25.09.2016 12:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '922'), 
('25.09.2016 13:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '970'), 
('25.09.2016 14:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '1264'), 
('25.09.2016 15:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '1338'), 
('25.09.2016 16:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '1347'), 
('25.09.2016 17:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '1491'), 
('25.09.2016 18:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '1637'), 
('25.09.2016 19:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '1544'),
('25.09.2016 20:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '974'),
('25.09.2016 21:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '503'), 
('25.09.2016 22:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '359'), 
('25.09.2016 23:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '218'), 
('25.09.2016 23:59:59', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '132')......`

The first element is the time value. The second is the measuring point. The third the amount of cars measured in that time interval.

There are 536 items in total.

For my program, I need the maximum of the third element in chunks of 12 (before noon, after noon).

For the maximum I've written the code:

`i = 0
topHour = []
for i in range(0, len(finalList), 12):
    values = max([int(i[-1]) for i in finalList[i:i+12]])
    topHour.append(values)`

This provides me with an output like this:

```
[922, 1637, ...]
```

However, how do I get the corresponding time value (first element) with it? In this very example the program should output `'25.09.2016 12:00:00'` and `'25.09.2016 18:00:00'` together with the maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate on the tuples (not on the last items in each tuple) and use the `key` function in `max` to get the last item that is used to compute the maximum.

You can do this with a *list comprehension*:

```
top_hour = [max(lst[i:i+12], key=lambda x: int(x[-1])) for i in range(0, len(lst), 12)]
#                            ^^^
print(top_hour)    
# [('25.09.2016 12:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '922'), ('25.09.2016 18:00:00', 'MQ100D1_3_1_4', '1637')]
```

Answer (score 0):

use the lambda function is appropriate, you can do it like:

```
max(finalList[i:i+12]], key=lambda x: int(x[-1]))
```

then you can process the triple further...

btw, in your code, the `i` is ambiguous, you should take care.